# Making Resharper put a space in-between class/namespace identifier and the curly brace

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper

I've just installed Resharper on my machine, and by default he presents me with the following C# code formatting:

```
namespace machineLearning{
    public class Class1{
    }
}
```

I've tried fiddling with the different options on `Options -> C# -> Formatting Style` but I can't seem to find what the option to correct this behaviour is. There seems to be no option explicitly or less-explicitly concerning adding a space between the identifier and the following brace.

How to accomplish that?

Comment: You'd need to inspect all the settings under the Braces layout section as detailed by awright18 below.. I think your settings are set to *End of Line (No space)*. Try changing all the required options (namespace, type, method) to *end of line (K&R style)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Resharper 7 It is under Resharper -> Manage Options -> Code Editing -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Braces Layout -> Method declaration -> (set the value to ) At End of line (K & R Style)

Comment: Thanks. I guess I wouldn't have guessed it had to be K&R style

Comment: My pleasure, I wasn't doing anything else at 3am :) Happy to help.